# Vim causing auto compile on file write

Tags: vim

I recently installed some plugins on vim, and since then every file write is triggering a build process, showing errors in the file (here's a C++ file):

[image]

The problem is, I'm pretty new to vim and am not sure which plugin is causing it. It'd be great if someone can help me out. I have the following in my `~/.vim/bundle`:

- minibufexpl.vim
- nerdtree
- syntastic
- tagbar
- tlib_vim
- vim-addon-mw-utils
- vim-snipmate
- vim-snippets

And here's my `~/.vimrc`:

```
syntax on
colorscheme papayawhip
set smartindent
filetype plugin indent on
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set number
set nowrap

"do not use the irritating red bg for highlighting errors
hi Error None

"load plugins in bundle automatically
execute pathogen#infect()

"autocmd vimenter * NERDTree

map <C-v> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
:nnoremap <C-n> :bnext<CR>
:nnoremap <C-p> :bprevious<CR>
```

Please help!

Comment: Nothing leaps out at me as causing that but I don't use all those plugins. I'd try doing a binary search for the plugin causing the problem by turning off half of them. If that fixes it, turn half back on, etc. If that doesn't point to anything and no one answers here, maybe ask again on http://vi.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @blm Genius idea! :D :D I'll try it if no other suggestion works. By the way, which plugins do you use/recommend to make vim work like an IDE?

Comment: @blm It worked! The culprit was Syntastic, which has a "helpful" file checker built in. Arrrrrrrgh!

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. From the Syntastic README: "Syntastic is a syntax checking plugin for Vim that runs files through external syntax checkers and displays any resulting errors to the user. This can be done on demand, or automatically as files are saved." I'd guess the "external syntax checkers" for C/C++ is just the C compiler with some options. Glad you found it!

Comment: Of course it's Syntastic. Why would you install that thing if you don't want what it does?

Comment: @romainl I installed these plugins because I was trying to learn what more can be done with vim. For now, I don't have the energy to fight with Syntastic.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably show you what plugin is doing it:

```
:verbose autocmd FileWritePre,FileWritePost
```

You will see several auto-commands, but the one that runs a `:make` will be the culprit.

Comment: No `make` here. Here's the full output: http://pastebin.com/0xjYWM2F

Comment: But removing plugins one by one solved it for me (see comments to original question). Thanks anyway! :-)

Comment: I assumed it would be triggering post-write, but it might be triggering pre-write, so I updated my answer.  Also, it's possible it wasn't actually running "`:make`", but since I don't know what the alternative would be, I left that part.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question so that it can be closed. As I removed plugins one by one, I found that the behavior was being caused by Syntastic.